# Make an usb video grabber driver

Tags: linux, video, usb, driver

I have buy an usb video grabber on ebay but I haven't received an official device, it's a fake, and this one is the only one fake not supported by Linux. I would like to write the linux driver, but I have no knowledge on driver dev. Where can I find tutorial for driver dev learning on linux?

The device is an easycap dc60++, identified as fushicai usbtv007. More details here : http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap#Known_Easycap_devices

It works on win7, so I can easily sniff usb protocol.

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Not a real answer, but some general strategy: Try to find a driver that you think is similar. Google around for other people reverse-engineering camera formats. Either add support for your device to an existing driver, or copy and modify a driver work on your device.  Don't be afraid to ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best way to learn how to develop drivers for the kernel is to take an existing driver (best if it's from mainline) that is similar to what you want and look at how they're doing it. For function references, head to your favourite [LXR site](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/) and search it up.

You could look up Linux driver development on Google and find some tutorials but I wouldn't recommend it for anything other than to get started since they're likely to be outdated or use deprecated kernel APIs.

Otherwise, there's always [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) if you don't want to get into the world of kernel driver development.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I made an experimental userspace driver for this device:

https://github.com/memeruiz/usbtv007

Hopefully somebody (or me) will take this and make a proper kernel driver for it.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a driver for the device in question (https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/6/10/381). There's a big space for improvement and I'd be very glad if you could get involved.

The following documentation is helpful:

- Linux Device Driver, third edition, book.

  - PDFs: http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/
  - epub: http://v3.sk/~lkundrak/ldd3/
- Video4Linux2 API: http://lwn.net/Articles/203924/
- Videobuf2 API: http://lwn.net/Articles/447435/

When it comes to a good example, have a look at the drivers/media/usb tree, particularly the stk1160 driver.

I didn't yet have a look at Federico Ruiz's libusb driver for the device, but it seems he mostly figured out the same things as I did about the hardware. I suggest you take a look at it though, as I'll certainly do.

Also, linux-media list is probably a better place to ask questions like this. I've got here mostly by accident and there certainly are much more capable people on the list.

Have a great day!